# Google Now Voice Search not resetting (voice search brings up old search result instead of re-searching)

Tags: google-voice-actions

In the past whenever I launched "Voice Search" on my android phone (Samsung S3), it would bring up the google voice search prompt, where it was actively listening to what I said (the phone on the left in the picture below).

[image: Voice Search]

It would then search google for whatever term I said, showing the search term at the top, and a browser on the bottom (the phone on the right in the picture). If I then existed the search, and opened a different app then went back and clicked on the shortcut to "Voice Search" it would again bring up a voice search prompt where it was actively listening to what I said again (back to the state on the left).

Now, if I perform a search, exit to another application, then click on the "Voice Search" application, it then REOPENS the search I already performed (the phone on the right), as opposed to starting a fresh new search (the phone on the left). That is not the desired action. I want it to start a fresh search every time I open "Voice Search". Is that possible, or is this what we are stuck with as a result of some recent update?